# How to have inter-module / inter-package foreign key constraints in Persistent

Tags: sql, postgresql, haskell, persistent

Since there are a lot of models in our DB, many of which operate fairly independently, we decided to define them in different modules. We then have a single `migrateAll` function that runs every migration in serial. It appears as though us doing this causes Persistent to not create foreign key constraints between the models, but I would really like those constraints to be there.

As a partial fix we could put them all into the same module, but we also have a separate package that depends on this first package that creates more models on top, again with some foreign keys. It would really hurt for us to have to merge those packages into one, when there is truly only a one-directional dependency between them.

Is there any way for foreign key constraints to still be created across modules? Perhaps by making it so that if you migrate a model with external foreign key constraints, the foreign model's migration is also ran. To avoid needing to order the migrations in dependency order.

It is also possible that the reason foreign keys are not being created is unrelated to this setup, but I can't seem to find anyone else running into the same issue, so I am assuming the above is the cause.

For an MCVE:

```
module Foo where

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateFoo"] [persistLowerCase|
Foo
    name String
|]
```

```
module Bar where

import Foo

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateBar"] [persistLowerCase|
Bar
    name String
    foo FooId
|]
```

```
module Models where

import Foo
import Bar

migrateAll :: Migration
migrateAll = migrateFoo *> migrateBar
```

Running `migrateAll` does everything I want except for create a foreign key constraint on the `Bar.foo` field. How do I go about getting that foreign key constraint while still keeping the modularity I want?

Comment: This question would be greatly improved by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DanielWagner Done, thanks!

Comment: I think the API added here solves this problem https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/pull/791

Comment: @MaxGabriel Thanks! Only thing is that it's non trivial to figure out where library dependencies end up on the file system, so I really need a way to `import` the tables I am building foreign keys too, not just read from a text file at compile time. This is because the dependencies of the package actually create their own tables that I need to migrate and create foreign keys to.

Answer (score 0):

Since `persistent-2.13.0` this is now possible using `mkPersistWith`. In your case:

```
module Foo where

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkEntityDefList "fooDefs"] [persistLowerCase|
Foo
    name String
|]
```

Note that I use `mkEntityDefList` to export the `EntityDef`s generated by TemplateHaskell to use them in `Bar`:

```
module Bar where

import Foo

share [mkPersistWith sqlSettings fooDefs, mkEntityDefList "barDefs"] [persistLowerCase|
Bar
    name String
    foo FooId
|]
```

Note also that I don't use the helper `mkMigrate` (using it currently does not work with `mkPersistWith` as it throws runtime errors). To migrate one can now use `migrateModels` instead:

```
module Models where

import Foo
import Bar

migrateAll :: Migration
migrateAll = migrateModels (fooDefs ++ barDefs)
```

This properly creates `ForeignRef`s, even updates old missing ones.